If a quantum channel is an isometry, is the channel also isometric?
This question may appear trivial at first, but comes down to an interesting naming convention in quantum information. Recall that

a quantum channel $\Phi:\mathbb C^{m\times m}\to\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is said to be isometric if there exists an isometry $V\in\mathbb C^{n\times m}$ such that $\Phi(X)=VXV^\dagger$ for all $X\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$, cf. Chapter 2.2.3 in the book "The Theory of Quantum Information" by Watrous (alt link) or, alternatively, this or this stackexchange answer.
a channel—or really any linear map—$\Phi:\mathbb C^{m\times m}\to\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is called an isometry (with respect to, say, the trace norm) if $\|\Phi(X)\|_1=\|X\|_1$ for all${}^1$ $X\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$. As a consequence, such channels preserve arbitrary state distances, that is, $\|\Phi(\rho)-\Phi(\sigma)\|_1=\|\rho-\sigma\|_1$ for all states $\rho,\sigma$.

As an example, every isometric channel is certainly an isometry because $VXV^\dagger$ has the same singular values as $X$ (as $(VXV^\dagger)^\dagger(VXV^\dagger)=VX^\dagger XV^\dagger$ and $X^\dagger X$ have the same eigenvalues) so the trace norm is always preserved. This begs the question whether the converse also holds and, as a consequence, whether these two notions are equivalent? In other words:

Question. If a channel $\Phi:\mathbb C^{m\times m}\to\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ satisfies $\|\Phi(X)\|_1=\|X\|_1$ for all $X\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ (i.e., $\Phi$ is an isometry), does there always exist an isometry $V\in\mathbb C^{n\times m}$ such that $\Phi(X)=VXV^\dagger$ for all $X\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ (i.e., $\Phi$ is isometric)?

There is one special case where is known to be true, and that is $m=n$. In that case one can take the high road and use an old functional analysis result of Russo (Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 23 (1969), 213)—or, in a slightly more general and more readable form, by Arazy (Isr. J. Math., 22 (1975), 247)—which states that every trace-norm isometry between spaces of the same dimension is either of the form $\Phi=U(\cdot)W$ or $\Phi=U(\cdot)^TW$ for some unitaries $U,W$. Combining this with the fact that $\Phi$ is completely positive yields $\Phi(X)=UXU^\dagger$ for all $X$ which is precisely what we had to show (recall that for $m=n$, every isometry $V\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is unitary by the rank-nullity theorem). But what about the general case where $m\neq n$?

${}^1$: To be clear, every channel restricted to states is an isometry (because $\|\Phi(\rho)\|_1={\rm tr}(\Phi(\rho))={\rm tr}(\rho)=\|\rho\|_1$)—the non-trivial property here is that $\Phi$ has to preserve the trace norm regardless of the input $X\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$, which is something not all channels satisfy. The simplest example which highlights this crucial distinction is the reset channel $\Phi(X)={\rm tr}(X)|0\rangle\langle 0|$ because
$$\|\Phi(\sigma_z)\|_1=\|{\rm tr}(\sigma_z) |0\rangle\langle 0|\,\|_1=0\neq 2=\|\sigma_z\|_1$$


(This is a Q&A style question meant as a contribution to the list of counterexamples in quantum information)

While the two concepts coincide for $m=n$, it turns out that in general not every channel which is an isometry is also isometric in the above sense. For a simple counterexample consider the channel $\Phi$ which extends any qubit by a second qubit in the maximally mixed state:
\begin{align*}
\Phi:\mathbb C^{2\times 2}&\to\mathbb C^{4\times 4}\\
X&\mapsto X\otimes\frac12{\bf1}
\end{align*}
Because the trace norm is a cross norm—i.e., $\|A\otimes B\|_1=\|A\|_1\|B\|_1$ for all $A,B$—$\Phi$ is a trace-norm isometry. However, its Choi matrix of $\Phi$ reads
$$
\mathsf C(\Phi)=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\simeq \frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\oplus\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\oplus{\bf 0}_4
$$
so ${\rm rank}(\mathsf C(\Phi))=2$. This means that $\Phi$ has at least two Kraus operators, hence it cannot be of the form $V(\cdot)V^\dagger$ for any $V$.
Indeed, a set of Kraus operators of $\Phi$ is given by $\{\frac1{\sqrt2}\iota_0,\frac1{\sqrt2}\iota_1\}$ where $\iota_j|x\rangle:=|x\rangle\otimes|j\rangle$ for $j=1,2$.
